# Solving a geometric-harmonic series

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

Find the value of $\displaystyle \frac21- \frac{2^3}{3^2}+ \frac{2^5}{5^2}- \frac{2^7}{7^2}+ \cdots$ till infinite terms.

found this problem while integrating $\arctan\left(x\right)/x$ from $0$ to $2$ using its Taylor series expansion
also tried writing $\arctan$ in complex $\log\left(\frac{1 + {\rm i}x}{1 - {\rm i}x}\right)$ form but could not get anywhere

is there any possible way to evaluate such harmonic geometric sequences

also can be seen that denominator is sum of odd squares which converges to $\pi^{2}/8$ if helpful

Comment: Why would you think that sum exists, that doesn't look like a series that  converges...

Comment: diverges ```https://wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+of+%282%5E%282n%2B1%29%2F%282n%2B1%29%5E2%29+*+%28-1%29%5En+from+0+to+infty```

Comment: A quick ratio test shows this series isn't convergent. The integral exists, but the integrand's Taylor series expansion does not have the radius of convergence needed to integrate across the whole interval $(0,2)$.

Comment: got it thanks! @Macavity

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_tangent_integral).

Comment: Diverges !!!. For example, if you change $2$ in the numerator for $a \in \left(-1,1\right)$, you'll get something related to $\operatorname{Li}_{2}$.